# Useful faculty sites that provide explanations of mathematical ideas

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I'm looking for resourses on undergraduate mathematics, explaining ideas behind well-known proofs, etc. What are some other sites like T. Tao's blog or T. Gowers'?

I.e. https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/mathsindex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Baez's site has some stuff: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/

In particular, he was one of the first people posting things like this on the internet, way back in the Usenet days when he published a "column" on mathematical physics, which are collected here: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/twfshort.html

Answer (score 1):

For a very fun free-wheeling discussion of (strange) ideas, give http://what-if.xkcd.com/ a try. That isn't quite what you asked for, but I'm confident more entertaining.